# How to recursively sort associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'd like to sort the following associative array:

```
$tree = [
  "id" => 245974,
  "children" => [
    [
      "id" => 111
    ],
    [
      "id" => 245982,
      "children" => [
        [
          "id" => 246093,
          "children" => [
            [
              "id" => 225892
            ],
            [
              "id" => 225893
            ],
            [
              "id" => 225902
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

## Desired sort order after the "search value" of `id` => `225902`:

```
[
  "id" => 245974,
  "children" => [
    [
      "id" => 245982, // <-- this is moved up
      "children" => [
        [
          "id" => 246093,
          "children" => [
            [
              "id" => 225902 // <-- this is moved up
            ],
            [
              "id" => 225892
            ],
            [
              "id" => 225893
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => 111
    ]
  ]
];
```

## What I've tried:

```
<?php

$category_id = 225902;

function custom_sort(&$a, &$b) {
  global $category_id;

  if ($a['id'] === $category_id) {
    return -1;
  }

  if ($b['id'] === $category_id) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (array_key_exists('children', $a)) {
    if (usort($a['children'], "custom_sort")) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  if (array_key_exists('children', $b)) {
    if (usort($b['children'], "custom_sort")) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

function reorder_tree($tree) {
  usort($tree['children'], "custom_sort");
  return $tree;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(reorder_tree($tree));
echo "</pre>";
```

## However, that returns:

```
[
  "id" => 245974,
  "children" => [
    [
      "id" => 245982, // <- this is moved up
      "children" => [
        [
          "id" => 246093,
          "children" => [
            [
              "id" => 225892
            ],
            [
              "id" => 225893
            ],
            [
              "id" => 225902 // <- this is *not* moved up
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => 111
    ],
  ]
];
```

How would I be able to also sort the `children` arrays?

Comment: What is the sort order after the "search value"?

Comment: @Andreas, I've updated the question so that the desired sort order afterwards is more clear

Comment: What I meant was: why is `225892` before `225893`? What happens if there is also a `225850` in there? Will that be before or after 225892 and 225893?

Comment: The `id`'s are arbitrary. What's important is to keep the original order for everything _except_ the matching `id` and all of its parents.

Comment: Your attempt is interesting, but it won't work because if there is only one element in the array as in `id=>245982`, `usort` won't recurse. I recommend not recursing in the comparator function for this reason.

Comment: @ggorlen yes, it appears that `usort` isn't called for arrays with length less than two. Do you recommend any other options? The reason for using recursion is because the number of levels of `children` will not be constant.

Comment: @ggorlen Additionally, even when adding an extra element so that `usort` is called, my attempt still doesn't work.

Comment: Right, if that one item happens to have an array of children that needs sorting, it will be ignored completely. The option is to use a regular recursive function but make the `usort` comparator non-recursive. The pseudocode is basically: are we at the deepest level? If so, do a sort and return whether the target id was found and report the result to the parent which sorts or not based on that result, and on the way up. Working on coding it.

Comment: Also, are we guaranteed that all ids are unique?

Comment: @ggorlen, no, there will be duplicates at different parts of the tree. The first match wins.

Comment: OK, duplicates are fine but I don't understand what "the first match wins" means.

Comment: @ggorlen ideally we'd only sort the first matching `id` and its parents, and keep all others in original order. However, at this point, it's fine to sort all matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great attempt and very much on the right track. The problem with recursion in the comparator is that `usort` will not call the comparator function when the array length is 1, so whether or not you explore the whole tree is at the whim of `usort`. This will abandon `id => 245982`'s branch of the tree.

The solution is to avoid recursing in the `usort`'s comparator function directly. Rather, use a regular recursive function that calls `usort` as needed, namely, the current array or a child array contains the target id. I use a separate array to keep track of which elements should be moved forward, but you can break out of the loop and splice/unshift a single element to the front if you prefer.

We can also make `$category_id` a parameter to the function.

Here's one approach:

```
function reorder_tree_r(&$children, $target) {
    $order = [];
    $should_sort = false;

    foreach ($children as $i => &$child) {
        $order[$i] = false;

        if (array_key_exists("children", $child) &&
            reorder_tree_r($child["children"], $target) || 
            $child["id"] === $target) {
            $order[$i] = true;
            $should_sort = true;
        }
    }

    if ($should_sort) {
        $priority = [];
        $non_priority = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($children); $i++) {
            if ($order[$i]) {
                $priority[]= $children[$i];
            }
            else {
                $non_priority[]= $children[$i];
            }
        }

        $children = array_merge($priority, $non_priority);
    }

    return $should_sort;
}

function reorder_tree($tree, $target) {
    if (!$tree || !array_key_exists("children", $tree)) {
        return $tree;
    }

    reorder_tree_r($tree["children"], $target);
    return $tree;
}


var_export(reorder_tree($tree, 225902));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'id' => 245974,
  'children' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 245982,
      'children' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 246093,
          'children' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'id' => 225902,
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'id' => 225892,
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'id' => 225893,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 111,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Nice answer ggorlen